# Can't vertically align this text inside a div

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I want to have both images and text inside these divs to be vertically centered.

I got the `img` to work with `top: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;`. Then I tried to vertically align the text by setting the `line-height` and `height` to the same height as the container but it doesn't center well, it's off by some amount.

How can I get this to work?

```html
<div class="border" style="border:1px solid red; width:100%; height:70px; position:relative;">
  <div class="border" style=" border:1px solid red; float:left; width:25%; height:100%; position:relative;"><!--contenedor facebook-->
    <img style="width:32px; height:32px; position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; margin:auto;"  src="">
 <a href="tel:+34646611421"><span style=" position:absolute; left:33px; line-height:70px; height:70px; font-family:Oswald, sans-serif; font-size:24px;">646611421</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="border" style=" border:1px solid red; float:left; width:25%; height:100%; position:relative;"><!--contenedor mail-->
     <img style="width:32px; height:32px; position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; margin:auto;"  src="">
 <span><a href="#" style="line-height:70px; height:70px; position:absolute; left:33px;">Mail Us</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks vertically centered, where do you see pixels off?

Answer (score 1):

It's not so clear, but there are many ways to center content with `display:flex;` and `justify-content:center;` in the style of the parent div.
Or you can play with `display:inline-block;` and `vertical-align:middle;` too

More informations [on this website for flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and this [Codepen for inline-block/vertical-align](https://codepen.io/edge0703/pen/iHJuA)

```css
div {
border:solid 1px #cc0000;
}

.flex-centered {

display:flex;
justify-content:center;
flex-direction: row;
flex: 2;
}

.flex-centered2 {

display:flex;
justify-content:center;
flex-direction: column;

}

.flex-centered3 {

display:flex;
justify-content:start;
flex-direction: row;

}
.vertical-middle {  }
.vertical-middle img, .vertical-middle a { display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;  }
```

```html
<div class="flex-centered">
   <div>Block 1</div>
   <div>Block 2</div>
</div>

<br />
<br />

<div class="flex-centered2">
   <div>Block 1</div>
   <div>Block 2</div>
</div>

<br />
<br />

<div class="flex-centered3">
   <div class="flex-centered2">
   Block 1
   </div>
   <div class="flex-centered">
    <div>Block 2</div>
    <div>Block 3</div>
   </div>
</div>

<br />
<br />

<div class="flex-centered3 vertical-middle">
  <div>
    <img style="width:32px; height:32px;"  src="">
   <a href="tel:+34646611421"><span>646611421</span></a>
  </div>
  <div><!--contenedor mail-->
     <img style="width:32px; height:32px;"  src="">
    <a><span>Mail Us</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```